# i have tried to dynamically disable the contact form 7 select box value which is already inserted into database

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

i have tried to disable the contact form 7 select box value which is already inserted.

I have tried to disable the time which is in select box :

```
<select id="timeval" class="form-control">
  <option value="11:00">11:00 am</option>
  <option value="12:00">11:00 am</option>
  <option value="13:00">11:00 am</option>
  <option value="14:00">11:00 am</option>
</select>
```

after inserting into db where i have matched both date and time to disable it but somehow ajax causing the issue in contact form7 where it submits on 404 page .
how can i properly do it without causing any harm to contact form7 .

Comment: I don't know if it's just me... but I'm confused.

Comment: How can you properly do what?

Comment: i have two select boxes 1 is date and the other one is of time .. when user submitted the form value inserted in contact form7db , i want to disable the time which is already submitted

Comment: What do you mean by `disable the time` ?

Comment: for example user submitted the value 11:00 , so it should not display again in the form

Answer (score 0):

You can remove elements by targeting them, then using remove() with jQuery.

```
$('#timeval option[value='X']').remove();
```

You will have to write out the code to handle the submission etc.